# A coin is tossed until a head turns up and $\$f(n)$ is paid out, find the expected value of the payment

Tags: probability, self-learning, expected-value

> A fair coin is tossed until heads turns up for the first time. If heads turns up for the first time on the nth toss you receive $2^n$ dollars.
>
> (a) Show that the expected value of your winnings does not exist (i.e., is
> given by a divergent sum) for this game. Does this mean that this game
> is favorable no matter how much you pay to play it?

I think $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 2^n(1/2)^n = \infty$. I'm not sure how to answer the second part of the problem, I think the answer is no but I can't think of a reason why.

> (b) Assume that you only receive $2^{10}$ dollars if any number greater than or
> equal to ten tosses are required to obtain the first head. Show that your
> expected value for this modified game is finite and find its value.

$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{9} 2^n(1/2)^n + \sum_{i=10}^{\infty} 2^{10} (1/2)^n $

$E(X)= 9 +  2^{10}(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1/2)^n) - \sum_{i=1}^{9} (1/2)^n)=9+2^{10}(1-0.998047)=11$

> (d) Now assume that the utility of $n$ dollars is $\sqrt{n}$. Write an expression for
> the expected utility of the payment, and show that this expression has a
> finite value. Estimate this value. Repeat this exercise for the case that
> the utility function is $log(n)$.

I'm really confused about what this question is asking, do I replace $2^n$ in the above with $\sqrt{n}$ and $log(n)$?

Edit:

if I sub in $\sqrt{2}^n$ for $2^n$

$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  \sqrt{2}^n(1/2)^n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{2}/2)^n = \frac{\sqrt{2}/2}{1-\sqrt{2}/2}=2.414$

if I sub in $log(2^n)$

$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  log(2^n)(1/2)^n = log(2)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}n(1/2)^n$ = 2log(2)$

Is any of the above correct?

Comment: You are supposed to take the root or log of the dollar amounts, i.e., of $2^n$, so repalce $2^n$ with $\sqrt{2^n}$ and $\log(2^n)$

Comment: In case you don't know yet, this is the famous [St Petersburg Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)